# Neo4j query for getting multiple connected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my graph, I want to get the first-degree, second-degree, and third-degree neighbors of a certain node. If my graph is `A -> B -> C -> D -> E`, then

- first-degree neighbor of C is B
- second-degree neighbor of C is A
- third-degree neighbor of C is none

When checking neighbors, I go in the reverse direction of the edge. To get these nodes, I wrote the following query.

```
MATCH (changedNode: Function) WHERE changedNode.signature IN [...]
MATCH (neig1: Function)-[:CALLS]->(changedNode)
MATCH (neig2: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig1)
MATCH (neig3: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig2)
RETURN DISTINCT neig1.functionName, neig2.functionName,  neig3.functionName
```

I realized that this code does not return B as the first-degree neighbor of C since A does not have any neighbors(neig3 is empty). In other words, this query requires a node to have a third-degree neighbor. I understood this but could not update my code. How should I revise my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OPTIONAL MATCH since A may not have a neighbor. Then the query will return a null value for neigh3.

```
MATCH (changedNode: Function) WHERE changedNode.signature IN [...]
MATCH (neig1: Function)-[:CALLS]->(changedNode)
OPTIONAL MATCH (neig2: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (neig3: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig2)
RETURN DISTINCT neig1.functionName, neig2.functionName,  neig3.functionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of **OPTIONAL MATCH** matches patterns against your graph database, just like a MATCH does. The difference is that if no matches are found, OPTIONAL MATCH will use a null for missing parts of the pattern. OPTIONAL MATCH could be considered the Cypher equivalent of the outer join in SQL.

```
MATCH (changedNode: Function) WHERE changedNode.signature IN [...]
MATCH (neig1: Function)-[:CALLS]->(changedNode)
OPTIONAL MATCH (neig2: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (neig3: Function)-[:CALLS]->(neig2)
RETURN DISTINCT neig1.functionName, neig2.functionName, neig3.functionName
```

For more explanation, visit: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/a-note-on-optional-matches/